# Asp.net meta name="description" with apostrophe

Tags: asp.net, html

I am dynamically loading the **meta name="description"** in my pages from the db. I have some content which contains apostrophe e.g

> Men's sweat shirt

When I inspect the page source I see the meta description as

```
Men&#39;s Sweat Shirt
```

Is this how it's supposed to be?

Yes, I am aware that google is less interested in my meta description, however, I would perfer to follow the proper guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best that way unless it bothers something. An apostrophe or single quote can break a lot of code if left unchecked. `&#39;` is the html escape sequence for an apostrophe. I'm actually surprised it hasn't broken anything in your database, as SQL uses single quotes as string delimiters.

If you feel you need to get rid of it, look into `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`

Comment: Single quotes only break SQL queries if you are concatenating strings instead of using parameterized queries. They are valid to store in any text column.

Comment: HtmlDecode wouldn't work as exposed here http://forums.asp.net/t/1340962.aspx/1/10 (but there's another working approach extending `HtmlMeta`)

Comment: @mgnoonan, that is correct. I didn't mean to insinuate that you can't store a single quote in a database. I've just seen it go wrong before.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - That seems to work. I extended the HtmlMeta and it's working so far on my test server. I owe you a vote for that recommendation (link).

Comment: @SaifKhan: Then add it as answer and accept it if it's working.